# Typescript passing component or DOM tag name

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hi I'm new to Typescript and currently straggling with how to type prop containing either HTML tag or react component. Here is my code

```
export interface MyProps {
 component: string | HTMLElement;
}

class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent<MyProps, State> {
 render() {
  const Component = this.props.component;
  return <Component ...>...</Component>
 }
}
```

usage:

```
<MyComponent component={({children}) => children} /> // any functional or class component
<MyComponent component="div" /> // any html tag div, svg...
```

Error I'm getting:

```
semantic error TS2604: JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures
```

Comment: Why not just `return {this.props.component}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically I see a mistake where you try to provide an actuals React/Html elements to create your components or Strings. This is not going to work the way you implemented, so my first solutions is to remove strings and just use elements such as `</div>, </h1>, </YourComponent>` and have your Props like this.

```
export interface MyProps {
 component: React.ComponentClass | HTMLElement;
}
```

However if you really want to keep that string as one of the options you will need to implement **React.createElement(component, props)** function, which should do what you want